# Does the low tolerance for opinion-based questions make the tag reality-check unnecessary?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-tag, opinion-based

It seems that no matter what you're asking about, if we  can't have an opinion based answer, then it must be based around some sort of reality check. Does the low tolerance for opinion-based questions make the tag [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) unnecessary? If not, please provide examples of answers that are both not opinion based, and not reality based.

Comment: I'd say that the tag [tag:magic] fits what you are asking about pretty good. You have to define your magic system and what you are trying to achieve. By using magic it is not [tag:reality-check] and by using objective criteria it isn't opinion-based. Please note that every question can be "opinion-based" when the author doesn't specify criteria that make an answer a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

No. Reality-check means that the answers can pick holes in the question’s premise. Such questions may be somewhat different in nature, as well.

I think you misunderstood the meaning of the tag.

Comment: If this is true, then the tag's description should reflect that, no?

Comment: What would you propose to change?  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/reality-check/info

Comment: Ah. I did not see the long description.